# HTML Layout: Prevent Fixed Footer from Covering Content

Tags: html, css, layout, position

**Important**: The target rendering engine is WebKit2, so browser compatibility isn't a concern.

I want the following layout:

```
        ____________    ____________________
       |            |  |                    |
       |            |  |                    |
       |            |  |                    |
       |   #sb      |  |        #act        |
       |            |  |                    |
       |            |  |                    |
       |            |  |                    |
..................................................
|                   # footer                     |
..................................................
```

where #sb and #act should have their own vertical scroll bars (when needed); and the footer is FIXED to the bottom and always shown.

I've managed to code this layout but haven't been able to fix an irritating bug - When #sb and / or #act have scrollbars (due to content that doesn't fit in them), and when you scroll down to the end, the damn footer overlaps and hides the last few lines (or any other content). As such, part of the content at the bottom isn't visible.

This is the code -

**HTML**:

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="sp">
            <div id="sb">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel libero congue, elementum ante vitae, porttitor sem. Cras pharetra ultrices mauris vel posuere. Sed rutrum enim tellus, eu facilisis risus vehicula et. Donec sagittis mattis nunc et vestibulum. Sed auctor purus et ullamcorper tincidunt. 
                And so on ...
            </div>
            <div id="act">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel libero congue, elementum ante vitae, porttitor sem. Cras pharetra ultrices mauris vel posuere. Sed rutrum enim tellus, eu facilisis risus vehicula et. Donec sagittis mattis nunc et vestibulum. Sed auctor purus et ullamcorper tincidunt. 
                And so on ...
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>&nbsp;</footer>
</body>
```

and the **CSS**:

```
@charset"utf-8";
 html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #d1cdc7;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}
#main {
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    min-width: 820px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: fixed;
    right: 5%;
    top: 10px;
}
#main #sp {
    overflow: visible;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 1%;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
}
#main #sp #sb {
    background-color: #F8F6F2;
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1%;
    height: 100%;
}
#main #sp #act {
    background-color: #F8F6F2;
    float: left;
    width: 66%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1%;
    height: 100%;
}
#footpad {
    height: 30px;
    clear: both;
}
footer {
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 27px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

... and the code in action on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sosam/9Lhgy/).

Can someone explain what's wrong?

Comment: Since the footer is fixed it will overlap the content.What exactly are you wanting ?

Comment: What exactly is the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: As the example in JSFiddle shows, when you scroll down to the bottom (on either #sb or #act), the last few lines can't be read because the footer blocks the view. I want the footer to be fixed at the bottom, but not block any content.

Comment: @Sam this is not a perfect fiddle.Just for output.Works for firefox which uses calc() http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/9Lhgy/1/ .So tell me is this type of output you are looking for?

Comment: @Zword: Yeah, exactly - with both #sb and #act touching the footer.

Comment: @Sam I will post an answer within 20 minutes.Check for it later

Answer (score 0):

To fix the footer problem in the css file under

```
#main {
bottom: 80px;  <--- use to be 0.... you can change it to whatever you want
left: 5%;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 20px;
max-width: 1920px;
min-width: 820px;
overflow: visible;
position: fixed;
right: 5%;
top: 10px;
}
```

I changed the bottom to no be the same as the footer so they don't stack. I don't know if that was the problem or not.

Add this code to the very top of the css file as a reset this might fix the problem with it not working in your browser.

```
   *{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   }
```

Comment: Same issue as @Zword - not fully satisfied as changing the height of the browser window changes the gap between #main and #footer. I want #main (and thus #sb and #act) to be touching the footer, but be above it so that no content gets blocked by the footer.

Comment: so change the value to bottom: 58px;

Comment: Resizing the window height changes the gap between #main and #footer. Irrespective of whether you give 80px or 58px, the gap changes on resize and is not constant. In JSfiddle, it seems to be constant, but when you open the HTML file in a stand alone browser tab / window the gap isn't constant on resize.

Comment: Try adding this reset to your css code *{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

Comment: No doesn't work. The gap still changes when the browser window is resized.

Comment: Wont the gap always change regardless because youre working with percentages and not fixed dimensions? Perhaps if what everyone is suggesting isn't working, you could add in break points for a responsive design?

Comment: @Bucthree What you say makes sense. Will explore the RWD option.

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-bottom:100px;` to **#main**

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/9Lhgy/4/)

---

## ***Copy-Paste the entire code below***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <style type='text/css'>
    @charset"utf-8";
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #d1cdc7;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

#main {
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    min-width: 820px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: fixed;
    right: 5%;
    top: 10px;
    padding-bottom:100px;
}
#main #sp {
    overflow: visible;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 1%;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
}
#main #sp #sb {
    background-color: #F8F6F2;
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1%;
    height: 100%;
}
#main #sp #act {
    background-color: #F8F6F2;
    float: left;
    width: 66%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1%;
    height: 100%;
} 
footer {
    background-color: #000;
    position: fixed;
    height: 27px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="sp">
        <div id="sb">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel libero congue, elementum ante vitae, porttitor sem. Cras pharetra ultrices mauris vel posuere. Sed rutrum enim tellus, eu facilisis risus vehicula et. Donec sagittis mattis nunc et vestibulum. Sed auctor purus et ullamcorper tincidunt. Suspendisse lacus purus, ornare nec augue sit amet, pulvinar malesuada metus. Morbi fringilla tempor ante quis elementum. In tempor odio arcu, vel suscipit metus mattis ac. Sed ac nulla ac lacus faucibus hendrerit. Etiam velit urna, pulvinar quis erat ac, cursus convallis lacus. Mauris non convallis orci, nec congue urna. Sed ac diam vitae erat porta viverra id nec tellus. Aliquam blandit nibh sed eros sollicitudin, ac ornare dui sagittis. Etiam semper, neque luctus feugiat facilisis, felis mi hendrerit augue, ut feugiat orci tellus vitae dui. Aenean ullamcorper consectetur quam sed dictum. Nam viverra elit lorem, sed eleifend augue interdum sit amet. Maecenas lacinia lectus eget vulputate tristique. Cras eget quam eu libero fringilla tincidunt. Aenean at nibh eget lacus vestibulum tristique ac sit amet nunc. Integer at vulputate neque, ut tempus purus. Etiam ac nunc odio. Aliquam tellus est, adipiscing sit amet enim vel, luctus egestas eros. Morbi in accumsan diam, nec commodo neque. Curabitur at nisl non magna venenatis vehicula. Duis non sagittis mauris, et fermentum nunc. Integer sapien nisi, mollis commodo pellentesque eu, rutrum volutpat ipsum. Etiam non scelerisque ligula. Donec iaculis lorem lorem, quis porttitor velit molestie eget. Nunc mollis nibh nec ipsum tincidunt, vel lobortis erat mattis. Suspendisse leo libero, blandit sit amet turpis non, tincidunt egestas nunc. Integer venenatis lectus justo, a sodales odio auctor ut. Morbi purus sem, rhoncus id magna non, eleifend blandit urna. Fusce bibendum augue non nisl aliquet ultricies. Praesent tincidunt lacus quis velit cursus, quis egestas nunc pretium. Pellentesque eu est ultricies, molestie lacus eget, consectetur erat. Nullam condimentum fringilla tempor. Morbi a pellentesque turpis. Curabitur ut elit nulla. Nam vitae sodales enim, vel dignissim nisl. Donec convallis pharetra sem consectetur molestie. Nulla semper ultrices neque non blandit. Pellentesque eget justo leo. Sed consectetur porttitor metus, vel fringilla sapien adipiscing ac. Pellentesque vel risus posuere, dapibus leo varius, fermentum arcu. Nulla in ligula luctus, molestie ligula vel, interdum est. Donec sed erat dolor. Sed cursus suscipit purus, ut eleifend enim vestibulum sit amet. Morbi elit felis, ornare vitae tellus ut, commodo ullamcorper leo. Cras faucibus, est quis vehicula blandit, tortor ante viverra tellus, at tristique metus erat eget lorem. Vivamus et auctor massa, ac commodo massa. Vestibulum magna mi, auctor nec ultrices ullamcorper, auctor sit amet urna. Nulla facilisi. Fusce purus libero, elementum nec ultricies molestie, pharetra at magna. Cras posuere dui in venenatis dignissim. Donec cursus augue eget lacus mattis, iaculis rutrum elit aliquet. Sed commodo, elit sit amet laoreet laoreet, est nunc euismod sem, eu consequat lorem lacus eget urna. In pharetra velit mauris, non vulputate odio sagittis a. Integer non vulputate velit. Nunc sed tellus molestie, egestas risus eget, pretium eros. Etiam vestibulum eget mauris a hendrerit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean at ipsum eu quam tincidunt dignissim. Etiam egestas eget orci non commodo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce semper aliquam dui, vehicula fringilla metus porttitor at. Curabitur mollis non tortor non hendrerit. Morbi ut nibh ut libero ultricies bibendum. Donec varius tincidunt tincidunt. Etiam bibendum consequat felis quis fermentum. Vivamus viverra varius urna a semper. Cras id mi velit. Aenean vitae nunc ullamcorper, sodales arcu ac, vehicula dolor. Proin dignissim ut odio pellentesque lobortis. Cras fermentum placerat arcu sed eleifend. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam sagittis urna eget dui tristique, eu dapibus justo pretium. Vestibulum tincidunt ante sed dictum feugiat. Praesent rhoncus quam a nunc pharetra ultricies. Quisque ac dictum massa, non consequat diam. Suspendisse iaculis ornare tortor volutpat malesuada. Curabitur non sollicitudin nunc, a congue lorem. Vivamus sed hendrerit dui. Phasellus eu libero gravida, eleifend est a, convallis orci. Integer aliquam, tortor vitae semper pretium, justo purus accumsan metus, sit amet vestibulum nisi orci at arcu. Vivamus eu nulla vel leo laoreet aliquet. Quisque at enim eros. Mauris pulvinar dictum felis, aliquet vestibulum odio cursus vitae. Proin diam nulla, condimentum non condimentum a, accumsan vitae felis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur nisl magna, viverra ac vestibulum semper, faucibus fermentum eros. Nunc a gravida eros, et imperdiet arcu. Nunc sit amet sagittis est. In ullamcorper fermentum lorem, vel hendrerit libero auctor nec. Suspendisse in lectus adipiscing, elementum felis vitae, tincidunt mi. Nunc tincidunt eros nisi, in ullamcorper metus dapibus nec. Vestibulum luctus risus ac nisl tincidunt scelerisque. Suspendisse volutpat velit tortor, eget auctor odio placerat at. Suspendisse tristique ligula ullamcorper massa venenatis cursus. Nunc sagittis enim eu feugiat suscipit. Suspendisse accumsan, augue vulputate placerat porta, dolor nulla sodales enim, a bibendum velit ipsum quis elit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam sed tempor eros. Suspendisse cursus enim nec dui bibendum, ut pellentesque urna adipiscing. Etiam sit amet eros ac massa sodales sagittis. Mauris eget tristique sapien. Maecenas felis dui, luctus quis dictum nec, scelerisque vel est. Vestibulum tristique velit ac ante viverra, eget malesuada nisl faucibus. Etiam consequat felis mi, et porta sapien faucibus id. Vivamus a mollis metus. Proin dapibus sollicitudin consequat. Pellentesque eu sollicitudin magna. Donec ac magna pretium, gravida mauris eget, egestas nulla. Pellentesque in hendrerit nunc. Sed vitae massa luctus, ultricies nisl eu, tincidunt nunc. Donec gravida mattis consequat. Cras quis sem molestie, faucibus dolor id, pretium mauris. Morbi sit amet leo sed leo tincidunt ultrices. Sed enim purus, adipiscing ut nisl vitae, accumsan scelerisque ipsum. Cras vitae felis lacus.
            THIS IS THE LAST LINE.
        </div>
        <div id="act">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel libero congue, elementum ante vitae, porttitor sem. Cras pharetra ultrices mauris vel posuere. Sed rutrum enim tellus, eu facilisis risus vehicula et. Donec sagittis mattis nunc et vestibulum. Sed auctor purus et ullamcorper tincidunt. Suspendisse lacus purus, ornare nec augue sit amet, pulvinar malesuada metus. Morbi fringilla tempor ante quis elementum. In tempor odio arcu, vel suscipit metus mattis ac. Sed ac nulla ac lacus faucibus hendrerit. Etiam velit urna, pulvinar quis erat ac, cursus convallis lacus. Mauris non convallis orci, nec congue urna. Sed ac diam vitae erat porta viverra id nec tellus. Aliquam blandit nibh sed eros sollicitudin, ac ornare dui sagittis. Etiam semper, neque luctus feugiat facilisis, felis mi hendrerit augue, ut feugiat orci tellus vitae dui. Aenean ullamcorper consectetur quam sed dictum. Nam viverra elit lorem, sed eleifend augue interdum sit amet. Maecenas lacinia lectus eget vulputate tristique. Cras eget quam eu libero fringilla tincidunt. Aenean at nibh eget lacus vestibulum tristique ac sit amet nunc. Integer at vulputate neque, ut tempus purus. Etiam ac nunc odio. Aliquam tellus est, adipiscing sit amet enim vel, luctus egestas eros. Morbi in accumsan diam, nec commodo neque. Curabitur at nisl non magna venenatis vehicula. Duis non sagittis mauris, et fermentum nunc. Integer sapien nisi, mollis commodo pellentesque eu, rutrum volutpat ipsum. Etiam non scelerisque ligula. Donec iaculis lorem lorem, quis porttitor velit molestie eget. Nunc mollis nibh nec ipsum tincidunt, vel lobortis erat mattis. Suspendisse leo libero, blandit sit amet turpis non, tincidunt egestas nunc. Integer venenatis lectus justo, a sodales odio auctor ut. Morbi purus sem, rhoncus id magna non, eleifend blandit urna. Fusce bibendum augue non nisl aliquet ultricies. Praesent tincidunt lacus quis velit cursus, quis egestas nunc pretium. Pellentesque eu est ultricies, molestie lacus eget, consectetur erat. Nullam condimentum fringilla tempor. Morbi a pellentesque turpis. Curabitur ut elit nulla. Nam vitae sodales enim, vel dignissim nisl. Donec convallis pharetra sem consectetur molestie. Nulla semper ultrices neque non blandit. Pellentesque eget justo leo. Sed consectetur porttitor metus, vel fringilla sapien adipiscing ac. Pellentesque vel risus posuere, dapibus leo varius, fermentum arcu. Nulla in ligula luctus, molestie ligula vel, interdum est. Donec sed erat dolor. Sed cursus suscipit purus, ut eleifend enim vestibulum sit amet. Morbi elit felis, ornare vitae tellus ut, commodo ullamcorper leo. Cras faucibus, est quis vehicula blandit, tortor ante viverra tellus, at tristique metus erat eget lorem. Vivamus et auctor massa, ac commodo massa. Vestibulum magna mi, auctor nec ultrices ullamcorper, auctor sit amet urna. Nulla facilisi. Fusce purus libero, elementum nec ultricies molestie, pharetra at magna. Cras posuere dui in venenatis dignissim. Donec cursus augue eget lacus mattis, iaculis rutrum elit aliquet. Sed commodo, elit sit amet laoreet laoreet, est nunc euismod sem, eu consequat lorem lacus eget urna. In pharetra velit mauris, non vulputate odio sagittis a. Integer non vulputate velit. Nunc sed tellus molestie, egestas risus eget, pretium eros. Etiam vestibulum eget mauris a hendrerit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean at ipsum eu quam tincidunt dignissim. Etiam egestas eget orci non commodo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce semper aliquam dui, vehicula fringilla metus porttitor at. Curabitur mollis non tortor non hendrerit. Morbi ut nibh ut libero ultricies bibendum. Donec varius tincidunt tincidunt. Etiam bibendum consequat felis quis fermentum. Vivamus viverra varius urna a semper. Cras id mi velit. Aenean vitae nunc ullamcorper, sodales arcu ac, vehicula dolor. Proin dignissim ut odio pellentesque lobortis. Cras fermentum placerat arcu sed eleifend. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam sagittis urna eget dui tristique, eu dapibus justo pretium. Vestibulum tincidunt ante sed dictum feugiat. Praesent rhoncus quam a nunc pharetra ultricies. Quisque ac dictum massa, non consequat diam. Suspendisse iaculis ornare tortor volutpat malesuada. Curabitur non sollicitudin nunc, a congue lorem. Vivamus sed hendrerit dui. Phasellus eu libero gravida, eleifend est a, convallis orci. Integer aliquam, tortor vitae semper pretium, justo purus accumsan metus, sit amet vestibulum nisi orci at arcu. Vivamus eu nulla vel leo laoreet aliquet. Quisque at enim eros. Mauris pulvinar dictum felis, aliquet vestibulum odio cursus vitae. Proin diam nulla, condimentum non condimentum a, accumsan vitae felis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur nisl magna, viverra ac vestibulum semper, faucibus fermentum eros. Nunc a gravida eros, et imperdiet arcu. Nunc sit amet sagittis est. In ullamcorper fermentum lorem, vel hendrerit libero auctor nec. Suspendisse in lectus adipiscing, elementum felis vitae, tincidunt mi. Nunc tincidunt eros nisi, in ullamcorper metus dapibus nec. Vestibulum luctus risus ac nisl tincidunt scelerisque. Suspendisse volutpat velit tortor, eget auctor odio placerat at. Suspendisse tristique ligula ullamcorper massa venenatis cursus. Nunc sagittis enim eu feugiat suscipit. Suspendisse accumsan, augue vulputate placerat porta, dolor nulla sodales enim, a bibendum velit ipsum quis elit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam sed tempor eros. Suspendisse cursus enim nec dui bibendum, ut pellentesque urna adipiscing. Etiam sit amet eros ac massa sodales sagittis. Mauris eget tristique sapien. Maecenas felis dui, luctus quis dictum nec, scelerisque vel est. Vestibulum tristique velit ac ante viverra, eget malesuada nisl faucibus. Etiam consequat felis mi, et porta sapien faucibus id. Vivamus a mollis metus. Proin dapibus sollicitudin consequat. Pellentesque eu sollicitudin magna. Donec ac magna pretium, gravida mauris eget, egestas nulla. Pellentesque in hendrerit nunc. Sed vitae massa luctus, ultricies nisl eu, tincidunt nunc. Donec gravida mattis consequat. Cras quis sem molestie, faucibus dolor id, pretium mauris. Morbi sit amet leo sed leo tincidunt ultrices. Sed enim purus, adipiscing ut nisl vitae, accumsan scelerisque ipsum. Cras vitae felis lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel libero congue, elementum ante vitae, porttitor sem. Cras pharetra ultrices mauris vel posuere. Sed rutrum enim tellus, eu facilisis risus vehicula et. Donec sagittis mattis nunc et vestibulum. Sed auctor purus et ullamcorper tincidunt. Suspendisse lacus purus, ornare nec augue sit amet, pulvinar malesuada metus. Morbi fringilla tempor ante quis elementum. In tempor odio arcu, vel suscipit metus mattis ac. Sed ac nulla ac lacus faucibus hendrerit. Etiam velit urna, pulvinar quis erat ac, cursus convallis lacus. Mauris non convallis orci, nec congue urna. Sed ac diam vitae erat porta viverra id nec tellus. Aliquam blandit nibh sed eros sollicitudin, ac ornare dui sagittis. Etiam semper, neque luctus feugiat facilisis, felis mi hendrerit augue, ut feugiat orci tellus vitae dui. Aenean ullamcorper consectetur quam sed dictum. Nam viverra elit lorem, sed eleifend augue interdum sit amet. Maecenas lacinia lectus eget vulputate tristique. Cras eget quam eu libero fringilla tincidunt. Aenean at nibh eget lacus vestibulum tristique ac sit amet nunc. Integer at vulputate neque, ut tempus purus. Etiam ac nunc odio. Aliquam tellus est, adipiscing sit amet enim vel, luctus egestas eros. Morbi in accumsan diam, nec commodo neque. Curabitur at nisl non magna venenatis vehicula. Duis non sagittis mauris, et fermentum nunc. Integer sapien nisi, mollis commodo pellentesque eu, rutrum volutpat ipsum. Etiam non scelerisque ligula. Donec iaculis lorem lorem, quis porttitor velit molestie eget. Nunc mollis nibh nec ipsum tincidunt, vel lobortis erat mattis. Suspendisse leo libero, blandit sit amet turpis non, tincidunt egestas nunc. Integer venenatis lectus justo, a sodales odio auctor ut. Morbi purus sem, rhoncus id magna non, eleifend blandit urna. Fusce bibendum augue non nisl aliquet ultricies. Praesent tincidunt lacus quis velit cursus, quis egestas nunc pretium. Pellentesque eu est ultricies, molestie lacus eget, consectetur erat. Nullam condimentum fringilla tempor. Morbi a pellentesque turpis. Curabitur ut elit nulla. Nam vitae sodales enim, vel dignissim nisl. Donec convallis pharetra sem consectetur molestie. Nulla semper ultrices neque non blandit. Pellentesque eget justo leo. Sed consectetur porttitor metus, vel fringilla sapien adipiscing ac. Pellentesque vel risus posuere, dapibus leo varius, fermentum arcu. Nulla in ligula luctus, molestie ligula vel, interdum est. Donec sed erat dolor. Sed cursus suscipit purus, ut eleifend enim vestibulum sit amet. Morbi elit felis, ornare vitae tellus ut, commodo ullamcorper leo. Cras faucibus, est quis vehicula blandit, tortor ante viverra tellus, at tristique metus erat eget lorem. Vivamus et auctor massa, ac commodo massa. Vestibulum magna mi, auctor nec ultrices ullamcorper, auctor sit amet urna. Nulla facilisi. Fusce purus libero, elementum nec ultricies molestie, pharetra at magna. Cras posuere dui in venenatis dignissim. Donec cursus augue eget lacus mattis, iaculis rutrum elit aliquet. Sed commodo, elit sit amet laoreet laoreet, est nunc euismod sem, eu consequat lorem lacus eget urna. In pharetra velit mauris, non vulputate odio sagittis a. Integer non vulputate velit. Nunc sed tellus molestie, egestas risus eget, pretium eros. Etiam vestibulum eget mauris a hendrerit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean at ipsum eu quam tincidunt dignissim. Etiam egestas eget orci non commodo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce semper aliquam dui, vehicula fringilla metus porttitor at. Curabitur mollis non tortor non hendrerit. Morbi ut nibh ut libero ultricies bibendum. Donec varius tincidunt tincidunt. Etiam bibendum consequat felis quis fermentum. Vivamus viverra varius urna a semper. Cras id mi velit. Aenean vitae nunc ullamcorper, sodales arcu ac, vehicula dolor. Proin dignissim ut odio pellentesque lobortis. Cras fermentum placerat arcu sed eleifend. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam sagittis urna eget dui tristique, eu dapibus justo pretium. Vestibulum tincidunt ante sed dictum feugiat. Praesent rhoncus quam a nunc pharetra ultricies. Quisque ac dictum massa, non consequat diam. Suspendisse iaculis ornare tortor volutpat malesuada. Curabitur non sollicitudin nunc, a congue lorem. Vivamus sed hendrerit dui. Phasellus eu libero gravida, eleifend est a, convallis orci. Integer aliquam, tortor vitae semper pretium, justo purus accumsan metus, sit amet vestibulum nisi orci at arcu. Vivamus eu nulla vel leo laoreet aliquet. Quisque at enim eros. Mauris pulvinar dictum felis, aliquet vestibulum odio cursus vitae. Proin diam nulla, condimentum non condimentum a, accumsan vitae felis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur nisl magna, viverra ac vestibulum semper, faucibus fermentum eros. Nunc a gravida eros, et imperdiet arcu. Nunc sit amet sagittis est. In ullamcorper fermentum lorem, vel hendrerit libero auctor nec. Suspendisse in lectus adipiscing, elementum felis vitae, tincidunt mi. Nunc tincidunt eros nisi, in ullamcorper metus dapibus nec. Vestibulum luctus risus ac nisl tincidunt scelerisque. Suspendisse volutpat velit tortor, eget auctor odio placerat at. Suspendisse tristique ligula ullamcorper massa venenatis cursus. Nunc sagittis enim eu feugiat suscipit. Suspendisse accumsan, augue vulputate placerat porta, dolor nulla sodales enim, a bibendum velit ipsum quis elit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam sed tempor eros. Suspendisse cursus enim nec dui bibendum, ut pellentesque urna adipiscing. Etiam sit amet eros ac massa sodales sagittis. Mauris eget tristique sapien. Maecenas felis dui, luctus quis dictum nec, scelerisque vel est. Vestibulum tristique velit ac ante viverra, eget malesuada nisl faucibus. Etiam consequat felis mi, et porta sapien faucibus id. Vivamus a mollis metus. Proin dapibus sollicitudin consequat. Pellentesque eu sollicitudin magna. Donec ac magna pretium, gravida mauris eget, egestas nulla. Pellentesque in hendrerit nunc. Sed vitae massa luctus, ultricies nisl eu, tincidunt nunc. Donec gravida mattis consequat. Cras quis sem molestie, faucibus dolor id, pretium mauris. Morbi sit amet leo sed leo tincidunt ultrices. Sed enim purus, adipiscing ut nisl vitae, accumsan scelerisque ipsum. Cras vitae felis lacus.
            THIS IS THE LAST LINE.
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>&nbsp;</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work as desired because changing the height of the browser window changes the gap between #main and #footer. I want #main (and thus #sb and #act) to be touching the footer, but be above it so that no content gets blocked by the footer.

Comment: What browser are you using.I tested it on firefox and the distance between them remains constant

Comment: Both Firefox and Chromium give me the same result. I tested it again - in JSfiddle the gap remains constant on resizing, but when you open the HTML file in its own tab / window the gap size change on resizing.

Comment: ***open the HTML file in its own tab / window*** ?

Comment: yeah- copy the HTML / CSS code into a file and open it. Resizing the window changes the gap.

Comment: @Sam I will try and reply

Comment: @Sam tested and works.Ok I will add the entire code of the fiddle.Copy-Paste it and then tell if it works

Comment: No it doesn't work. Change the width of the browser and observe. When you resize both the height and width of the browser, from a very small size to the maximum (1920 px) you can see the gap changing.